# Disable GetTouch after 1st touch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object which I want to throw at certain distance by GetTouch. My code is working but the problem is when I touch the screen multiple times,the object also moves multiple times. I don't want the object to move multiple times. I want my object to move only one time no matter how many times I touch or swipe the screen. Here's something I tried.

```
public class RealBallMove : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
public Rigidbody rb;


void Start() 
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update() 
{
    if (Input.touchCount >0 &&
        Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended || (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)))
    {
        //rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * speed);
        //rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * speed);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().isKinematic = false;

        GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (new Vector3(0.0f, 20.0f, 12.0f));
        //Destroy (GetComponent<Rigidbody>());
    }
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a boolean indicating whether you have thrown the ball ;)

```
public class RealBallMove : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    private bool thrown ;


    void Start() 
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        if (
            !thrown && (
            (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended ) ||
            Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) )
        )
        {
            rb.isKinematic = false;
            rb.AddForce (new Vector3(0.0f, 20.0f, 12.0f));
            thrown = true ;
        }
    }
}
```

An other option would be to disable the script when the touch is detected, but only if you script is just the lines above and nothing else.